# Play a sound on another web page via button click

Tags: javascript, ajax

Direct to the point of my problem. I have a web app that have like queue management system. The app will be use by teacher to call a student base on their queue. There was 2 page in my app that I want to connect to each other.
Page 1 is a home page that teacher login to their account. In this page there is a button [NEXT QUEUE].
Page 2 is a real time queue for each teacher.

When the button in page one is pressed, the page 2 will update next queue automatically (using ajax). It behave like a chat app so I follow this simple tutorial [TUTSPLUS SIMPLE WEB CHAT](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-create-a-simple-web-based-chat-application--net-5931) and change a little to make it works in my web app.

Then my problem is how to play a beep sound in page 2 when a teacher pressed the button ? I can't find tutorial to play a song on other page, what I found is only the same single page. The simpler solution will be checking the button pressed, but I don't know how to check that if it in another page. I'm very newbie in ajax and not so proud with my javascript skill so I only follow tutorial above.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can use `postMessage()` to communicate between browsing contexts.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `window.postMessage()` to communicate between different browsing contexts

Page 1

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>   
  <head>
  </head>    
  <body>       
    <button>click</button>
    <a href="page2.html" target="_blank">open page2</a>
    <script>
    var src;
      document.querySelector("button")
      .onclick = function() {
        src.postMessage("clicked", src.location.href);
      }
      window.onmessage = function(e) {
        console.log(e.data);
        src = e.source;
      }
    </script>
  </body>    
</html>
```

Page 2

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>    
<head>
</head>    
<body>    
  page2
  <script>
    window.onload = function() {
      if (this.opener.location.href === document.referrer) {
        this.opener.postMessage("message from page2", document.referrer)
      }
    }
    window.onmessage = function(e) {
      console.log(e.data);
      var audio = new Audio("/path/to/audio");
      audio.oncanplay = function() {
        this.play()
      }
    }
  </script>
</body>    
</html>
```

plnkr http://plnkr.co/edit/EsqQ8dPEQZoTHqhvE0Uy?p=preview